# Prove orthogonality of $\sin (nx)$ $(n = 1, 2, 3, \dots)$ from interval $[0, \frac \pi 2]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, orthogonality

This question was given by my teacher recently and I got it wrong (despite completing similar problems from the textbook). The main trouble I had was trying to prove the orthogonality of these functions with the given interval (since $\sin(\frac \pi 2)$ is $1$ and not $0$ like I am used to solving). I just want to know if it is possible to prove these functions are even orthogonal on this interval, or if it was a trick question and they are not in fact orthogonal. Apologies for the wordy question, but thank you in advance!

[question is in the title]

Comment: $\sin (nx) \sin (mx)=\frac 1 2[ \cos ((n-m)x)-\cos ((n+m)x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you defining the inner product by integration? If so, Kavi Rama Murthy's hint is very good, as you can turn multiplication into addition.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the inner product by integration, but when I simplified the integral and substituted the interval using the resulting (1/2)[sin(n-m)x/(n-m)] - (1/2)[sinn+m)x/(n+m)]  i dont know if that simplifies to zero thus proving orthogonality . . . I might have miscalculated though

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\sin(2x)\;dx = \frac{2}{3} \ne 0.$$

Since both functions are positive on $[0,\pi/2]$ we can see (even with no calculation)  that the inner product is not $0$.

Comment: Okay, that clears it up for me. Thank you so much! For some reason I thought the general form could be simplified to zero but this makes sense.